How to update $PATH after installing PHP (OSX)
I've successfully installed PHP 8.1 on my OSX Catalina computer using homebrew.  I can see the new version is installed in /usr/local/opt/php@8.1
Various other SO posts indicate that to up update $PATH, I should do this:
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/php@8.1 :$PATH
When I do that, I get the error "`:/usr/local/opt/php@8.1': not a valid identifier", not sure where the ":" before the filepath came from.
I thin the export command only sets the php path for the current Terminal session and elsewhere on SO, I see I should add the same export command to my ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file but neither of those files exist in my user directory (yes I am configured to see hidden files).  Once the problem with the export command is resolved, should I simply create on of profile/bashrc files and add it export to the new file.
Thanks for any help, you can probably tell, I hardly everr use Terminal commands.

It looks like you have a space character between @8.1 and the following colon.  If you take that out, the command should work for the current shell.
You are probably running zsh rather than bash, so look for a .zshrc file and try adding your export command there.

I tried that and it wiped out all the existing $PATH entries leaving just the one I tried to add.  I had an ecjo output of $PATH so was able to resore the contents of $PATH.
